# How can I OAuth 2.0 authorise a Google API service with google-api-ruby-client 0.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-api-ruby-client

With my OAuth 2.0 client ID of type Web Application I've retrieved an access token, which I've stored in a Token object. Now I'd like to exchange that access token for access to Gmail API methods.

The service is instantiated:

```
gmail = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
```

Now I want to test getting labels:

```
@labels = gmail.list_user_labels('me')
```

This needs authorisation first.

In Google API Ruby Client 0.9 ["the authentication and authorization code was moved to the new googleauth library."](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/MIGRATING.md)

Googleauth, however, appears to depend on loading in the `client_secrets.json` file, but this doesn't seem appropriate for a production environment.

Is there a way around this without having to downgrade to Google API Ruby Client 0.8 or 0.7.1?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in the [Authentication Overview](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/aaa_overview), client secret is required for the OAuth 2.0 authorization.

There are two types of authentication:

> 1. *Simple API access (API keys)*
>
>    - These API calls do not access any private user data. Your application must authenticate itself as an application belonging to your Google Developers Console project. This is needed to measure project usage for accounting purposes.
> 2. *Authorized API access (OAuth 2.0)*
>
>    - These API calls access private user data. Before you can call them, the user that has access to the private data must grant your application access. Therefore, your application must be authenticated, the user must grant access for your application, and the user must be authenticated in order to grant that access. All of this is accomplished with [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) and libraries written for it.

---

> *Client ID and client secret:* These strings uniquely identify your application and are used to acquire tokens. They are created for your project on the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). There are three types of client IDs, so be sure to get the correct type for your application:
>
> - Web application client IDs
> - Installed application client IDs
> - Service Account client IDs

You may want to check [Exchange the authorization code for an access token](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server#exchange_the_authorization_code_for_an_access_token) (Python Sample) for code implementation on how to exchange access token.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'm supplying the client secret via environment variables on the server already and have already acquired an access token.